# Pypi: can I claim to be the new maintainer of an unmaintained package?

Tags: python, django, pypi, django-hstore

I have done quite a lot of work on a python package named **"django-hstore"** recently (link to my repo: https://github.com/nemesisdesign/django-hstore), the latest version published on pypi has been released more than a year ago (link to pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-hstore/1.1.1), but the very curious thing is that the github repository linked on pipy is not the one of the original author.

Moreover, this github user doesn't seem to have any commit with its github account (https://github.com/aino/django-hstore). He hasn't answered so far to my email and pull request, what happens if he doesn't answer at all?

My questions are:

1. Can I claim to be the new mantainer of this package? Is there a way to do so?
2. Have ever happened a similar occurrence?

> Note:
>
> I'm sorry if this question is not specific about programming, but I
>   think it's still related to programming somehow... if there is any
>   better stackexchange site to ask this question please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process has been documented in [PEP 541, How to request a name transfer](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0541/#how-to-request-a-name-transfer).

> If you want to take over an existing project name on PyPI, these are
> the steps to follow:
>
> 1. Try to contact the current owner(s) directly: email them and open an
>    issue if you can find a related repository. The processes described
>    here are meant as a last resort if the owner cannot be contacted.
> 2. Check the criteria above to see when a transfer is allowed. In
>    particular, the criteria for reusing a name for a different project
>    are more stringent than for continuing maintenance of the same project.
>    Although, it's not easy to get a name transferred in either case.
> 3. Search the [PyPI Support issues](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues) to see if anyone else is already
>    requesting the same name.
> 4. If all the criteria are met to transfer
>    ownership of the name, open a new issue to request it, detailing why
>    you believe each relevant criterion is satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

You could try filing a [support request](http://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/) to take over the package; I don't believe PyPI has native support for it however.

Comment: opened support ticket here: http://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/327/

I hope they will answer!

Comment: They replied it was better to get in touch with the owner. In the end I reached the owner, I looked for his name and contacted on his personal email, a bit intrusive.. but it worked :)